Как сделать взаимодействие с объектом как в Симс? Unity
Мне для игру нужна механика взаимодействия с объектами как в Симс (игрок кликнул на объект мышкой, появилось окно с вариантами, игрок выбрал действие и так далее). Подскажите, как можно такое сделать на Unity?

Что бы реализовать такую механику нужно:
Создать в инспекторе специальный слой, к примеру objects.
Создание слоёв unity
Объекту по которому будет тыкать игрок нужно назначить этот слой objects в инспекторе.
Далее нужно написать код который будет выпуская луч Raycast получать gameObject на который тыкнул игрок и проверять его слой. Если слой у полученного при Raycast объекта равен objects - открываем UI меню в котором реализовываем задуманные механики выбора.
Инструкция Physics.Raycast
Инструкция GameObject.layer
